# Remapping Alt Key to Space bar and Using Profiles

Tags: dota-2, autohotkey

So in DOTA 2 I would like to use space bar a key modifier, like ALT does. so I remapped the ALT key to Space Bar and vice versa using AutoHotkey. The problem is, when I am chatting to my team mates, I have to use the ALT key as a space. Is there a way to make it so that I could use say Num1 and Num2 (any key is fine, I have rebindable keys on my keyboard), to switch between the remapped version of my keys and the original usage of the keys, like a profile system?

Edit: Changed wording for clarification.

Comment: Are you trying to bind space bar to alt so that the camera behaves similarly to League of Legends?

Comment: Nah, in Dota 2 you can set keybinds so that you can have ALT+Key uses an ability or somesuch, problem is, you can only use the ALT key for this, not the space or CTRL etc. So what I want to do is map space to alt but be able to revert it back to its original function (space) so I can chat in game and such.

Comment: My thought is to make enter (and escape) toggle this specific AutoHotkey state. So when you press enter to send a message, it switches spacebar back to spacebar, and when you've sent your message with enter it switches back to being ALT.

Comment: Honestly, this is probably better off being asked in a different Exchange site - it's not really about anything other than AutoHotkey

Comment: try to work with those commands: `dota_remap_alt_key 0 ` "Specify a key to use instead of the alt key in-game." and `dotadev_bind ` "For development: Bind a key to in dota (ALT+key) allowed." taken from: http://dota2.gamepedia.com/List_of_Console_Commands

Answer (score 2):

This is an old question but because I got an answer I thought I could share it.

I think this is exactly what I did for myself https://github.com/bemug/dota2cfg

The good news is that it can be done right in source scripting, you don't need external tools.

Basically I remap the space key to a modifier using source script, and when I press space, it execute a file containing some bindings. When I release it, it execute another file overriding these bindings with new ones.

```
alias +keyShift "exec bindingsOnPress"
alias -keyShift "exec bindingsOnRelease"
bind "SPACE" "+keyShift"
```

Hope this helps :)